# Python Django - Why does Django make 2 calls to the DB for one request

Tags: python, django

For the below code I noticed that the backend is makeing 2 calls to the DB.

```
userApps = CustomerUserMapping.objects.filter(user=user).values_list('customer__applicationName', flat=True)
```

This results in

```
[07/Feb/2018 12:51:30] DEBUG [django.db.backends:90] (0.004) SELECT "core_customers"."applicationName" FROM "core_customer_user_mapping" INNER JOIN "core_customers" ON ("core_customer_user_mapping"."customer_id" = "core_customers"."customerId") WHERE "core_customer_user_mapping"."user_id" = 'xxx' ORDER BY "core_customer_user_mapping"."user_id" ASC, "core_customers"."customerName" ASC, "core_customers"."customerId" ASC LIMIT 21; args=('xxx',)

[07/Feb/2018 12:51:30] DEBUG [django.db.backends:90] (0.000) SELECT "core_customers"."applicationName" FROM "core_customer_user_mapping" INNER JOIN "core_customers" ON ("core_customer_user_mapping"."customer_id" = "core_customers"."customerId") WHERE "core_customer_user_mapping"."user_id" = 'xxx' ORDER BY "core_customer_user_mapping"."user_id" ASC, "core_customers"."customerName" ASC, "core_customers"."customerId" ASC; args=('xxx',)
```

Can anyone provide a explanation for this. Or tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: It's not coming from just this line. Please show the full view and template.

Comment: This is not part of a view,  its part of a backend function. When I comment out that line. Both debug messages get removed.

Comment: Are you running this with your IDE's  debugger on?

Comment: is [it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/HPPSWypI9OM) your case? Also read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/PkzS9Wv6hIU/discussion) why 21.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes I am running it with an IDE

Comment: By itself, the one line you posted does not make __any__ db access (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

Comment: E.g. the PyCharm Debugger sometimes evaluates variables at breakpoints which can cause extra queries. Not sure if this is your case though.

Comment: I am using Eclipse. If you note there is a slight difference between the debug messages with one having a limit and the other without it.

Comment: @WilletteLynch it really looks like the behaviour mentionned here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/HPPSWypI9OM

Comment: Well that does provide a decent explanation. Thank you. I will just have to accept it as it is.